# In Firefox, click() does not run right after setting checkbox.disabled = false

Tags: javascript, firefox, checkbox, onclick, wicket

I am writing some Javascript for an Apache Wicket page and am trying to create a "Select All" checkbox that, when checked, will check all of the other checkboxes and then disable them. Similarly, when dechecked, it will enable and uncheck all of the checkboxes. This checkbox will not be updated by the rest (that is, selecting all of the other checkboxes will not select the Select All box).

I can accomplish what I want using checkbox.checked = selectAll.checked but it doesn't seem to pass in a click event, which I need for some functionality in Wicket. Using checkbox.click() gives me the click events I need but doesn't seem to run after re-enabling the checkboxes.

```js
var selectAll = document.getElementById("all");

function checkbox_changed() {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');

  for (var i in checkboxes) {
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];

    checkbox.disabled = false;

    if (checkbox.checked !== selectAll.checked) {
      //checkbox.checked = selectAll.checked;
      checkbox.click();
    }

    if (selectAll.checked) {
      checkbox.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="all" onchange="checkbox_changed()">Select All
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo">One
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo">Two
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo">Three
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo">Four
  <br>
</form>
```

In case its easier, here is a jsfiddle of the above: https://jsfiddle.net/ytggu5as/

EDIT: I just realized this is only happening in Firefox (I'm using 39.0) and updated the question. It seems to be okay in Chrome and Safari (haven't tested any others). Any idea why this is happening and how to get around it? If not, is there a better alternative to `.click()` than just using `.checked`?

Comment: try checkbox.checked = true instead of click().

Comment: If a checkbox is disabled, how can you click it?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the Select All box, it never gets disabled but enables/disables the rest. As for the others, I'm trying to call click() after re-enabling them.

Comment: Alternatively you could do all this with Wicket AjaxCheckBox, rather than Javascript. Ajax is where Wicket really shines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that calling `click()` **after** reenabling the checkbox doesn't work seems to be a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963529).

You could work around the bug by setting `disabled=false` in a first pass, then inside a `setTimeout(..., 0)` iterate over the checkboxes again and call `click()` as needed.

Comment: Ya, I started to figure as much. Thanks for the confirmation. I ended up getting around it by setting focus to the checkbox after enabling it, though I wasn't happy with that cause I also have to call blur() to get rid of the unwanted focus. I'll give your suggestion a shot.